# Azure Virtual machines slow startup

Tags: azure, virtual

I have 2 azure vm's created, 1 windows server 2012 r2, and 1 Ubuntu 14.
It takes both those vm's approximately 5 minutes to startup.

Is there a way I can speed up the process?

I don't need the vm's running continuously, I prefer to start/stop, as per need.

Comment: This question was asked 5 year ago, seems like the startup time is still as slow as before. Is there new tricks to make the startup time faster? For comparasion, AWS t3 series start up time is around 1 mins, the startup time different is quite large...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no steps you can take to speed up the VM start. Resources must be allocated and the VM provisioned.

What I can recommend is setting up a script to auto start / stop your VM's based on a schedule. For example, if you are using them in a class room environment you can set it up so that they start early (6am?) and shut down each day by 5pm.

You can find some more information about this [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Start-Windows-Azure-b6c179b6).

Comment: You are welcome. Can you please mark as answer when you have a moment?